# Make Directories in Batch File based on list

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to create a batch file that will create directories for multiple names.

This is what I'm trying to do:

List of Names:

```
Bob
Billy
Joe
Sue
Clide
```

```
SET Year=2014
SET Month=05

FOR (1 to Names)
SET Name = FOR ( Names )
MKDIR %Name%\%Year%\%Month%
```

Except I don't have a clue how to possibly do that. Does anyone know how to loop through names or a general list with a batch file?

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the `Names` are stored in a separate file `names.txt` you can try like below

```
@echo off
SET Year=2014
SET Month=05
for /F %%a IN (names.txt) DO mkdir %%a%Year%%Month%
```

Which will result in folder with names as shown below

```
Billy201405  
Bob201405  
Clide201405 
Joe201405   
Sue201405
```

**EDIT:**

If you decide to store the names in a variable then you can do like this

```
@echo off    
set "names=Bob Billy Joe Sue Clide"
SET Year=2014
SET Month=05
for %%s in (%names%) DO mkdir %%s%Year%%Month%
```

**FINAL EDIT:**

Not sure but if you are looking for creating folder in hierarchy like `Bob\2014\05` then below code will do

```
@echo off    
SET Year=2014
SET Month=05
for /f %%s in (names.txt) do mkdir "%%~s\%Year%\%Month%"
```

**EDIT_10th_MAY:**

Considering that your file contains names with spaces like below

```
Bob Johnson
Billy Cheng
Joe Watson
Sue Me
Clide Wilsen
```

You can use below code block

```
@echo off    
SET Year=2014
SET Month=05
for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%s in (names.txt) do mkdir "%%~s\%Year%\%Month%"
```

Which will create folder as below

```
Billy Cheng\2014\05
Bob Johnson\2014\05
Clide Wilsen\2014\05
Joe Watson\2014\05
Sue Me\2014\05
```

Comment: @Stephan, yes that's not needed. Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks! Does that make the directories inbetween as well? IE: C:\Bob\2014\05?

Comment: @user2296381, NO, as mentioned in my answer; it will create a single directory with name like `name+year+month`; like `billy201405`. I believe that's what you are looking for as per your post.

Comment: @user2296381, see edited answer to handle spaces in names. I went by your original post. You should clarify everything in your post.

Answer (score 0):

This should reliably create the folder tree in the current directory:

```
@echo off
SET Year=2014
SET Month=05
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%a IN ("names.txt") DO md "%%a\%Year%\%Month%"
```

Comment: This will create folder like `Bob\05` instead of `Bob\2014\05`

Comment: @Rahul It had a `%` sign misplaced.  That's been fixed.

Comment: Quick Question for Everyone - What if the Names Include spaces, such as Bob Johnson? It isn't accounting for the spaces it seems.

Comment: This solution does handle spaces.  What do you get in the folder?